# How do you make a bullet point with a double bullet character in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have a bulleted list in InDesign but I want the bullet character to be shown twice.
I'm using the / character, so I want it to appear like // like a comment. I can't figure it out. I have the bullet a different colour/style as the text following it, so I don't want to "hard-code" it in either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the trolls fellow.  Your question isn't a programming question, which is why you got a downvote.

However, to help you out, try using a font for your bullet point that has a glyph that you like - you can use any character for the bullets, you know.

Or, if you create a new paragraph style, you can go into the Paragraph Style Options under Bullets and Numbering.  Now, where it says Text After you can enter another bullet character there. But you'll have to also create a character style to set it to the right font to show your bullet character.